# Control when the scrolls in a ScrollPane show up

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a scroll pane that the scrolls show up only when elements like buttons start to disappear, which is pretty small. I want to control when the scrolls show up so they'll appear earlier.

I couldn't find a way to it, is there a property or listener to do this?

Comment: You have two properties like vbarPolicyProperty() and  hbarPolicyProperty()  for showing the scroll bar, maybe you can use these?

Comment: What would they scroll if they appear before anything is out of bounds?  

If you want a "scroll beyond edge of pane" functionality, the simplest solution is probably to add an empty pane at the end.

Comment: ScrollPane has AnchorPane inside, so you can set this AnchorPane bigger and then scroll, also when you don't have any controls inside.

Comment: @sillyfly Not beyond a pane but they show up only when the window is really small and the other panes became pretty small as well, also labels are disappearing before the scroll show up: http://image.prntscr.com/image/bf914e6bfeb54f66b62cdcb0a8983b6b.png

Comment: I set the scene to be 2/3 of the screen size so how can the anchorPane be bigger? @BadVegan

Comment: Ah, it looks like your labels are resizing before the `ScrollPane` has a chance to add scroll bars. Try setting the minimum width of the labels (`USE_PREF_SIZE` should work), and maybe minimum sizes of other components you don't want to shrink.

Comment: @sillyfly yeah that fixed it, thanks.